# Reading csv file with long header line containing special characters

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I was trying to read the Toxic Release Inventory (TRI) csv files which I downloaded from [Here](https://www.epa.gov/toxics-release-inventory-tri-program/tri-basic-data-files-calendar-years-1987-2016) using the command `tri2016 <- fread("TRI_2016_US.csv")` but it gives me a warning about discarding line 1 has too few or too many items to be column names or data.

However, `tri2016_1 <- read.csv("TRI_2016_US.csv")` reads it without giving any errors and correct column names!  Using `tri2016_1 <- fread("TRI_2016_US.csv", header=TRUE)` still generates the warning and still ignores the header.

The TRI files have 108 columns and the header row contains special characters.  The list of columns are listed in [Pdf file](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2016-11/documents/tri_basic_data_file_format_v15.pdf) (Appendix A on pg 7).

Is there any way to get `fread` to read these csv files along with the header?
 Or should I just stick with `tri2016 <- as.data.table(read.csv("TRI_2016_US.csv"))` and not worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header line seems to have a trailing comma (one more than in the other rows) - tested with `TRI_2016_US.csv` - 111 columns.

If you remove that, the problem should be solved.

Comment: Maybe the data.table authors can check this in their header testing code and generate a possible warning to check too?  Thank you @Danny_ds .

Answer (score 0):

Try the readr package.

```
library(readr)
tri2016_1 <- readr::read_csv("TRI_2016_US.csv")
```

You'll get a warning saying

```
Warning messages:
1: Missing column names filled in: 'X112' [112] 
2: In rbind(names(probs), probs_f) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```